# Burninate [react-redux]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-redux) has 15 questions. All but one of them were also tagged with [redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux). I added [redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux) to the single question that did not have the tag.

[redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux) currently has 818 questions. It looks like [react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-redux) is completely redundant.

In addition, it has no wiki.

Should we burninate [react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-redux)?

Comment: It's probably just me, but I kinda prefer the opposite of that. [react-redux] will not become ambiguous if someone else invents another framework/library called redux. Besides that, is there really the need to burn this tag? Both tags are meaningful, it's not something like [once] or [extract]. Isn't this what tag synonyms are for?

Comment: But then again redux can be used with other frameworks like angular. However, there are other frameworks that are named redux already which gets to be quite annoying when googling for react-redux resources. So yes, probably best to get rid of redux tag and keep react-redux.

Comment: Even though I suggested getting rid of react-redux, I actually agree that it makes more sense to do the opposite. It's the newer, less used tag but on its own its much more descriptive. The way these two tags are currently used, they completely overlap and they should definitely be sent to tag *thunderdome*.

Comment: If there are other libraries named Redux, renaming it to [tag:redux-js] might make more sense?  There is a [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) library that provides React bindings for [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux), but I don't know how many of those questions are specifically about that library.

Comment: Yeah, echoing what a couple of other people have already said, the tag for [redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux) shouldn't have "react" in the  name and it may be useful to have 2 different tags to distinguish between questions about redux and those about [react-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux). Questions about react-redux are always about redux in a very general sense, but not vice versa.

Comment: It’s funny looking at this request years later now that there are thousands of questions on each.  As @JMM said, react-redux questions are also about redux but not vice versa.  Redux doesn’t require that it be used in a React app (though it almost always is).

Comment: I think we could still use better usage guidelines.  If the question has to do with the connect HOC, useSelector, useDispatch, or “why isn’t my component updating?” then the react-redux tag is warranted.  If the question is just about the creation of the store itself, like issues with reducers or actions, then it should just be redux and not react-redux.  My two cents.